# List to Dictionary via LINQ ToDictionary(...)

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq, dictionary

I currently have some difficulties converting a list to a dictionary.
The list looks like this:

```
List<Assignment> list = new List<Assignment>();

public class Assignment {
    public String Id      {get;}
    public String Name    {get;}
    public String Product {get;}
    public String Content {get;}
}
```

Since both Id and Name appear in the list multiple times, Id and Name form a compound key.
Product and Content together represent one entry each.

A tuple of Id and Name is used to determine a list of all associated product / content combinations:

```
Tuple<string, string> // string1 = Id, string2 = Name
```

The question is: How can the list be transformed into the following form by using the LINQ extension method ToDictionary()?

```
Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, ICollection<Tuple<string, string>>>
```

The result should be a dictionary that provides a list of all products and their contents as follows:

```
dict.TryGetValue(Tuple.Create("123", "Username"), out collection);
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: No, it's not homework.
I experimented a bit with the Linq-expression itself and something came out in that direction:
.ToDictionary (x => Tuple.Create (x.Id, x.Name), x => new List <Tuple <string, string >> ())
However, this results in an ArgumentException because it attempts to add the key multiple times.
And to be honest, my LINQ-knowledges are still pretty fresh.

Comment: Are you sure `Id` is not unique? If it is not unique, why did you name it `Id`?

Comment: It is not unique. The use case is similar to battle tags in the Blizzard environment, where names can occur multiple times due to an associated number and together uniquely identify a user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will first need to group the elements by their compound key. Afterwards you can generate the dictionary.

This can be done as follows:

```
var dictionary = assignments.GroupBy(x=>new Tuple<string,string>(x.Id,x.Name))
                            .ToDictionary(
                                group => group.Key, 
                                group => group.Select(x => new Tuple<string,string>(x.Product,x.Content)).ToList());
```

If you are using C# >= 7.0 you can use [tuple literals](https://gunnarpeipman.com/net/tuple-literals/) in order to avoid calling the tuple constructor.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate answer is to use `.ToLookup()` instead of `.ToDictionary()`. Simply:

```
var lookup = list.ToLookup(x => (x.Id, x.Name), x => (x.Product, x.Content));
```

And then you can use as follows:

```
var collection = lookup[("123", "Username")];
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
var collection = lookup[(Id: "123", Name: "Username")];
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your alternative solutions!
Although this is a solid possibility in the context of my request, the following processing requires a dictionary with the given characteristics.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have neater-looking code, you can use [Named Tuples (C# 7.0)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/new-features-in-c-7-0/) with inferred member names, as following:

```
var dict = list.GroupBy(x => (x.Id, x.Name))
               .ToDictionary(
                   g => g.Key,
                   g => g.Select(x => (x.Product, x.Content)).ToList());
```

And then you can use as follows:

```
dict.TryGetValue(("123", "Username"), out List<(string, string)> collection);
```

or, if you prefer:

```
dict.TryGetValue((Id: "123", Name: "Username"), out List<(string, string)> collection);
```